# Where is Library-Win32 on Delphi 10.3.3?

Tags: delphi

Recently i upgraded from D2007 to 10.3.3 and i simply could not find where is the equivalent option of this on the new Delphi :

Tools > Options > Environment Options > Delphi Options > Library - Win32

Where is this on the 10.3.3 ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tools > Options > Language > Delphi Options > Library

See the [Library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Library) documentation in Embarcadero's DocWiki.